# Pandas replace DataFrame values based on multiindex values

Tags: python, pandas, replace, conditional-statements, multi-index

I have two dataframes, where the first dataframe indexes/columns relate to the second dataframe indexes/columns. In **df1**, the columns are the months of **df2**, and the rows are the low layer of the indexes. I want to distribute **df1** in **df2** based on that relation. Here is a simplified example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], index= [1,2], columns=[1, 6])

index_list = [[1, 1, 2, 2],[1,2,1,2]]
header_list = [np.datetime64('2020-01-01'), np.datetime64('2020-06-01'),np.datetime64('2021-01-01'),np.datetime64('2021-06-01')]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=index_list, columns=header_list)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of work but no major obstacle.

```
df1.index.name, df1.columns.name = 'key', 'month'
df2.index.names, df2.columns.name = ['a', 'key'], 'date'
x = df1.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'value'})
y = df2.fillna(0).stack().reset_index(level=-1).drop(0, axis=1)
y['month'] = y['date'].apply(lambda z: z.month)
y = y.reset_index().merge(x, on=['key', 'month']).drop('month', axis=1)
y = y.set_index(['a', 'key', 'date']).unstack('date')
```

Comment: there is a mistake in the provided example. Year of last date shoudl be `2021`

Comment: You are right, fixed it. Your code works, thanks! I was wondering if there was a simplier way to do this :)